# Error installing MAGeCK - unknown packages required

Tags: python

I tried to follow the MAGeCK-VISPR following the installation instruction from
https://bitbucket.org/liulab/mageck-vispr/src/master/

```
conda create -n mageck-vispr  python=3.11.4
conda activate mageck-vispr
conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge mageck-vispr
```

and the error I received is as such

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): / DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
- DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
- DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                 

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Not entirely sure what is wrong. It does not tell me which packages I need.
I am using M2 Mac.

Thanks for your inputs.